# c++ unit testing using Boost

Tags: c++, unit-testing

I am really new to Unit testing, and I have the following really basic program:

```
#include "stdafx.h"


// classes example
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class CRectangle {
    int x, y;
  public:
    void set_values (int,int);
    int area () {return (x*y);}
 bool isEq ();
};

void CRectangle::set_values (int a, int b) {
  x = a;
  y = b;
}

bool CRectangle::isEq () {
  if(x==y)
  {
   return true;
  }
  else
  {
   return false;
  }


}
int main () {
  CRectangle rect;
  rect.set_values (3,3);
  cout << "area: " << rect.area();
  cout << "  isEq: " << rect.isEq() << "  \n";
  return 0;
}
```

I want to know how do I test the method isEq? I want 100% code coverage of this method and I want to use the Boost test framework. Any ideas? I am using VS 2009 SP1, what do I build and run? I am very confused with Unit testing.

**UPDATE:**

Thanks Stuart, however what Im doing is still not making sense. I know have the following code with the following file names:

```
//FILENAME: test.cpp
#include "stdafx.h"
#define BOOST_TEST_MODULE isEq Test
#include <boost/test/included/unit_test.hpp>
#include "CRectangle.h"

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(isEq_test)
{
    CRectangle rect;
    rect.set_values(5,5);
    BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(rect.isEq(), true);
    rect.set_values(23,9);
    BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(rect.isEq(), false);
}
```

---

```
// FILENAME: CRectangle.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "CRectangle.h"
//#include <boost/test/included/unit_test.hpp>

// classes example
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


void CRectangle::set_values (int a, int b) {
  x = a;
  y = b;
}

bool CRectangle::isEq () {
  if(x==y)
  {
      return true;
  }
  else
  {
      return false;
  }


}

int main () {
 CRectangle rect;
 rect.set_values (3,3);
 cout << "area: " << rect.area();
 cout << "  isEq: " << rect.isEq() << "  \n";
 return 0;
}
```

---

```
//FILENAME: CRectangle.h
//void CRectangle::set_values (int a, int b);
//bool CRectangle::isEq ();

#ifndef CRECTANGLE_H
#define CRECTANGLE_H

class CRectangle {
    int x, y;
  public:
    void set_values (int,int);
    int area () {return (x*y);}
    bool isEq ();
};


#endif
```

---

```
// FILENAME: stdafx.h : include file for standard system include files,
// or project specific include files that are used frequently, but
// are changed infrequently
//

#pragma once

#include "targetver.h"

#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>



// TODO: reference additional headers your program requires here
#ifdef _UT
#define ut_private public
#define ut_protected public
#else
#define ut_private private
#define ut_protected protected
#endif
```

I want to remind you that I am using Visual Studio 2008 SP1 (running this project as a win32 console app). Whenever I build the following files it gives me errors. I am also unsure how the Boost lib is supposed to give me results of my test??? Will a new window open up??? What will happen exactly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest way to test it is to do something like this (I'm not attempting to write great test cases, I'll leave that to you):

```
#define BOOST_TEST_MODULE isEq Test
#include <boost/test/included/unit_test.hpp>

#include "CRectangle.h"

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(isEq_test)
{
    CRectangle rect;
    rect.set_values(5,5);
    BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(rect.isEq(), true);
    rect.set_values(23,9);
    BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(rect.isEq(), false);
}
```

No need to build Boost.Test if you do that, you just include the header and away you go. Hope that helps a bit!

p.s. As a side comment, you might want to pick a naming scheme for your functions and stick to it -- having both `set_values` and `isEq` looks a bit inconsistent, for what it's worth...

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but I am still  confused, which header am I meant to include? Am I meant to write the header file myself. I am not a c++ programmer by trade, however I know c relatively well.

Comment: Also where do I put the code that you wrote above? Should I put it in another .cpp file? or the same file as the code I wrote in my first post (name demonstration.cpp). Also how do you write my header file?

Comment: By "include the header", I meant the one in the above code, i.e. `boost/test/included/unit_test.hpp`. The way I structured things was to have a library with all the stuff I wanted to test in it, then I wrote the main program and a set of unit test programs which linked against the library. Each unit test program just looks a bit like the above, but includes the header file of whatever you're trying to test, e.g. `#include "CRectangle.h"`. You don't need a `main` function in your test programs -- Boost.Test handles that all automatically -- you just need to write the sort of thing shown above.

Comment: support I have class skeleton in CRectangle.h and definition in CRectangle.cpp, how would the test method get reference to the class method?

Comment: @PriteshAcharya: You need to add `#include "CRectangle.h"` to your test file, as mentioned in the previous comment.

Comment: @StuartGolodetz adding just the class declaration won't allow me to create the object in the test method.

Comment: @PriteshAcharya: What error message are you getting?

Comment: undefined reference. the workaround i used is, I included the .cpp file.

Comment: @PriteshAcharya You have to link CRectangle.cpp with your test program. There is no difference to when you use CRectangle in a normal program.

Answer (score 2):

To continue the answer :

The class and functions in the source file need to be exported, so that they can be used in the Unit test file as follows :

`//CRectangle.h`

```
#define DLLEXPORT __declspec(dllexport)

class DLLEXPORT CRectangle
{
...
}

// CRectangle.cpp

void DLLEXPORT  CRectangle::set_values (int a, int b)
{
...
}

bool DLLEXPORT  CRectangle::isEq ()
{
..
}
```

On compiling the CRectangle source.lib.

Finally link the Unit Test program with source.lib, include "CRectangle.h" and call
the functions in CRectangle.

Hope this helps..